# A list of all data types you get by calling DataTypes in c#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of documentation for all the data types you can get in c# by using the DataType command, i.e.,

```
[DataType(DataType._DataTypeHere_)]
```

?

I'm very new to c# (literally started learning it yesterday) but I've just been put on a work project involving it and I'm not really sure of what DataType means/does. I've tried looking it up but I always come away with more questions than I went in with! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Click somewhere inside the DataType word and press F1 to jump to online help.

Comment: @Isma Sorry, like I said, I'm new to this. Obviously I wasn't searching the right thing to get that result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the MSDN docs. The [`DataTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679282(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a type of [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) and that has a list of Members:

```
CreditCard  
Currency    
Custom  
Date    
DateTime    
Duration    
EmailAddress    
Html    
ImageUrl    
MultilineText   
Password    
PhoneNumber 
PostalCode  
Text    
Time    
Upload  
Url
```

Of course, your intellisense in Visual Studio should also give you this information.